# Changing output of `pd.DataFrame.isin` to `True` if column is omitted

Tags: python, pandas

If I pass a dictionary to the `isin` method of a dataframe, columns that are omitted in the dictionary are considered `False` by default.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['foo'] = pd.Series([0, 0, 1, 1, 5, 5], dtype='category')
df['bar'] = pd.Series([4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1], dtype='category')
values = {'foo' : [0, 1]}
print(df.isin(values))

Out[1]: 
     foo    bar
0   True  False
1   True  False
2   True  False
3   True  False
4  False  False
5  False  False
```

This is annoying* because if I have a dataframe with many columns and I only want to impose conditions on a subset of them, I still have to list all names of the other columns with all their possible values. Is there an elegant way to avoid that?

*I later want to select the rows in which a condition holds, `row_mask = df.isin(values).all(axis=1)` so I would like all columns for which no condition is imposed to be `True`.

Comment: Why don't you slice the DataFrame `df[subset_of_cols].isin(values).all(axis=1)`? `subset_of_cols` can be accessed with `values.keys()` too I guess.

Comment: Yep I think this is what I want `row_mask = df.loc[:, values.keys()].isin(values).all(axis=1)`, good one.